# (Un)marshall JSON with named root for Ember Data using Scala case class on Spray

Tags: scala, ember-data, spray, spray-json, json4s

I am writing a RESTful interface and I would like to marshall and unmarshall JSON ready for Ember Data.
The wrinkle is that Ember Data wants the entity name and the two libraries I've tried, spray-json and json4s, don't appear to do this easily.

Desired [Ember Data](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) format

```
{
  "coursePhoto": {
    "photoId": 1
  }
}
```

Current default format:

```
{"photoId":15}
```

This should come from a case class:

```
case class CoursePhoto(photoId: Long)
```

I did get it running with the following custom code:

```
object PtolemyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object CoursePhotoFormat extends RootJsonFormat[CoursePhoto] {
  def write(cp: CoursePhoto) =
    JsObject("CoursePhoto" -> JsObject("photoId" -> JsNumber(cp.photoId)))  
  def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
    case coursePhotoJsObject: JsObject => {
      CoursePhoto(coursePhotoJsObject.getFields("CoursePhoto")(0).asJsObject
      .getFields("photos")(0).asInstanceOf[JsArray].elements(0)
      .asInstanceOf[JsNumber].value.toLong)
    }            
    case _ => deserializationError("CoursePhoto expected")
  }
}
```

That code seems horrifyingly fragile and ugly with all the `asInstanceOf` and `(0)`.

Given that I'm writing in Spray with Scala what's the nice way to get named root JSON output? I am quite happy to do this with any JSON library that integrates nicely with Spray and is reasonably performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following solving your problem?

```
scala> import spray.json._
import spray.json._

scala> import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

scala> case class CoursePhoto(photoId: Long)
defined class CoursePhoto

scala> case class CoursePhotoEmber(coursePhoto: CoursePhoto)
defined class CoursePhotoEmber

scala> implicit val jsonFormatCoursePhoto = jsonFormat1(CoursePhoto)
jsonFormatCoursePhoto: spray.json.RootJsonFormat[CoursePhoto] = spray.json.ProductFormatsInstances$$anon$1@6f5d66b6

scala> implicit val jsonFormatCoursePhotoEmber = jsonFormat1(CoursePhotoEmber)
jsonFormatCoursePhotoEmber: spray.json.RootJsonFormat[CoursePhotoEmber] = spray.json.ProductFormatsInstances$$anon$1@401a0d22

scala> """{ "coursePhoto": { "photoId": 1 } }""".parseJson.convertTo[CoursePhotoEmber]
res0: CoursePhotoEmber = CoursePhotoEmber(CoursePhoto(1))

scala> res0.toJson
res1: spray.json.JsValue = {"coursePhoto":{"photoId":1}}
```

Comment: Ah! Now I realize where I was confused. I was trying the wrapped approach but was getting tied up with my business logic returning `CoursePhoto` but having two `JsonFormat[CoursePhoto]`'s in scope. Embarrassingly, I didn't think about simply creating a `CoursePhotoEmber`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem made me wonder if it were possible to do it in a re-usable way. I believe I've figured out a reasonable way to do this for multiple types.

```
object PtolemyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val CoursePhotoFormat = new NamedRootFormat("CoursePhoto", jsonFormat1(CoursePhoto))
}
import PtolemyJsonProtocol._

class NamedRootFormat[T](rootName: String, delegate: RootJsonFormat[T]) extends RootJsonFormat[T] {
  def write(obj: T): JsValue = {
    JsObject((rootName, delegate.write(obj)))
  }
  def read(json: JsValue): T = json match {
    case parentObject: JsObject => {
      delegate.read(parentObject.getFields(rootName).head)
    }
    case _ => deserializationError("CoursePhoto expected")
  }
}
```