# Scala Case Class Json Transform With Named Root

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am currently working on a small and easy Rest API using the Playframework 2.4 with Scala. I did define a simple case class and this gets transformed into Json rather easy. Now I would like to have the object (and if the result is an list, each entry in this list) named.

Is this possible in an easy manner? I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097871/unmarshall-json-with-named-root-for-ember-data-using-scala-case-class-on-spray), but it does not really solve my issue.

```
case class Employee(name: String, address: String, dob: Date, joiningDate: Date, designation: String)

// Generates Writes and Reads for Feed and User thanks to Json Macros
implicit val employeeReads = Json.reads[Employee]
implicit val employeeWrites = Json.writes[Employee]
```

So, right now I do get

```
{
  "name": "a name",
  "address": "an address",
  ...
}
```

But I would like to see something like:

```
"employee": {
  "name": "a name",
  "address": "an address",
  ...
}
```

For a list of objects the same rule should apply:

```
"employees": [
  "employee": {
    "name": "a name",
    "address": "an address",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

This possible using the given Writes Macros? I am slightly lost right now ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expect is not valid JSON, i.e. you would have to have your examples wrapped in curly braces to denote an object - because the top-level JSON element must be an object, an array, or a string, number, boolean, or `null` literal. If having the result wrapped in curly braces is acceptable for you, i.e.

```
{
  "employee": {
    "name": "a name",
    "address": "an address",
    ...
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "employee": {
        "name": "a name",
        "address": "an address",
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

then creating a wrapper case class should solve it for you:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

// instead of using `reads` and `writes` separately, you can use `format`, which covers both
implicit val employeeFormat = Json.format[Employee]
case class EmployeeWrapper(employee: Employee)

implicit val employeeWrapperFormat = Json.format[EmployeeWrapper]
implicit val employeesWrapperFormat =
  (__ \ "employees").format[List[EmployeeWrapper]]
```